# Does typescript return type of variable only when it is assigned some value after type declaration?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

In type script, is it possible to get the type of a variable before assigning any value to it?

```
let a: number;
console.log(typeof a);
```

returns `undefined`

where as

```
let a: number;
a = 10;
console.log(typeof a);
```

returns `number`

Comment: Typescript doesn't exist once it is transpiled to javascript.  It's just there to help you know what stuff is.

Comment: No, it's not possible. The type system exists *at compile time* when the code executes *at runtime* the type system and *all of TypeScript* is not there. You only have JavaScript. `typeof a` will *only* give you the JS type, not the TS one - e.g., `let a: {foo: number} = {foo: 42}; typeof a` will print `object` as that's what JS knows about.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to use `typeof` here? After all, you already know upfront that `a` will be a number.

Comment: As the two comments above explain - typescript only helps you during compile time. When the javascript is actually executing in the browser it has no knowledge of the types that you specified.

Comment: Just started learning typescript and angular. Just wondering how it works with different syntax. That's it. No specific reason.

Comment: You don't know what you don't know.  It's a solid question.  Now you know, :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Types are erased in TypeScript. They don't exist at runtime.

In fact, TypeScript has *no runtime semantics at all*. TypeScript *cannot possibly change* the result of the code from what the result would be in plain ECMAScript.

What you are using in your code snippet is the *ECMAScript* `typeof` operator, it has nothing to do with TypeScript, and it doesn't know anything about TypeScript.

Comment: "*What you are using in your code snippet is the ECMAScript typeof operator, it has nothing to do with TypeScript, and it doesn't know anything about TypeScript.*" I feel like TS having their own `typeof` operator is just needlessly confusing for newcomers since it leads to there being two of them that do different things.